# Pandas: Group By two categories and return count

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame( {'type' :  [0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2], 'category' : ['A','B','A','B','C','A']})
```

Or in a visual way:

```
   type  category
0   0   A
1   1   B
2   2   A
3   2   B
4   0   C
5   2   A
```

I want to group my data into type (lines), and show the count of each category as columns, so my desired output would be somewhat like:

```
type  A  B  C
  0   1  0  1
  1   0  1  0
  2   2  1  0
```

So far I tried the following codes, but node returned me anything close to what I need:

```
data.groupby(['type', 'category']).agg('count')

data.pivot_table(index = 'type', columns = 'category', aggfunc = 'count')
```

What is wrong and what can I do to do this transformation?

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['type'], df['category'])`?

Comment: `df.groupby('type')['category'].value_counts().unstack('category', fill_value=0)`

Comment: Wow, both seem to work well and do exactly what I need. Care to elaborate what they do?